# base64 to image convert and upload live server using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, base64

I am having trouble for this work.

I want to save a image to live server which I get base64 data.
when I use localhost that's fine to work. But when I use live server using hosting it seems wrong.

Hosting file uploading size 138 MB now.
What could I do know.

Thanks.

my code:

```
$("#btn-save").on('click', function() {
    html2canvas($(".canvas-container"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

            $.ajax({
                url:'save.php',
                type:'post',
                dataType: "json",
                data:{
                    base64data:imgData
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    showToast(data.status, data.message);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    showToast("error", 'Failed to save!');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

php code:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['base64data'];
$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$image = explode('base64,', $data);
$file = 'images/'.  time(). '.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, base64_decode($image[1]));
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO img_tbl (title, image) values ('$title', '$file')");
```

Comment: you never told what problem you are facing on the live server any error or exceptions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please go through how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), please make your question Minimal, Complete, Verifiable [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for coding question which have to can be reproduced to help you.

Comment: What exact problem are you having? Is it perhaps CORS related?

Comment: oky, thanks all, 
i found it, it's problem in my hosting . my hosting is so much disgusting that's why i faced this problem.
when i change my hosting and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

oky, thanks all, 
i found it, it's problem in my hosting . my hosting is so much disgusting that's why i faced this problem.
when i change my hosting and work properly.